# Hanns-G HZ201 19" LCD monitor

Tags: display, lcd

I'm an old tv man and it looks like there is no red. My house took a lightning strike thru the ethernet and fried all of my comm stuff. This monitor is hooked up to a puter that didn't seem to be hurt. The monitor powers up okay and you can see everything but its difficult. Computer powers up okay and accesses internet. I have taken the monitor apart and there is no obvious damage. I'm not that familier with LCD technology so my question is .... is this likely a problem with the power supply board, the interface board (pcb with db connectors), or backlight? And the follow up question would be...where to get the part?

Comment: How is the computer connected to the monitor? VGA? With plain old analog VGA we used to commonly see the problem where one connector was dodgy and one color was missing as a result.

Comment: Yes it was connected vga. Turned out to be the cpu motherbd vga output bad. Got a dvi cable and hooked up and works fine.

Comment: Are you sure it's the VGA output port? Did you try different VGA cables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing the color red can have a few causes.

1. The cable has been damaged or is not securely fitted into both sockets
2. The port at either the monitor or pc is damaged
3. the filter layer for red coloured pixels is damaged (unlikely)

I would first try a different cable and connect the monitor to a different pc and also connect a different monitor to your pc to localize the problem. Once you localized the problem, you can look into fixing the issue.

Comment: Thks I will try that

Comment: You were right. The cpu was the problem. Interestingly though, I got a dvi cable and hooked the monitor up to that and it works. Vga is inop but dvi is okay. That saves me some cash since it is an integrated motherboard! Thanks again, you saved me.

Comment: Its not the CPU, as the CPU (Central Processing Unit) is not responsible for the graphics, but the GPU (Graphical Processing Unit) is. You can still have an on-board GPU though, but in this case its likely either the VGA cable or one of the Sub-D (VGA) connectors gone bad. Have you tried with a different VGA cable? Then you know for sure its just the cable or a component on your computer/monitor.